# PHP - Dropdown menu(select) not working properly to while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I want my dropdown-textbox-select(I'm confused what it really is) to query all the data in the appropriate table I want to display. But it is displaying all the data with separated dropdown-textbox-select. I just want the data to be inside. Here's what I'm doing so far.

```
<?php   


    $sel_admin = "SELECT * FROM author";
    $rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin))
                {
                echo '<select class="form-control">';
                echo"  <option value='volvo'>" . $row['author_firstname'] . $row['author_lastname'] ."</option>";
                echo'</select>';
                }
                ?>
```

PS. If the user click submit, I want the author_id to be save, instead of the name. How can this be also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select` tag should be outside of the `while` loop : you want only one select field, containing options with all the fetched rows.

```
echo '<select class="form-control">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin))
{
    echo"  <option value='volvo'>" . $row['author_firstname'] . $row['author_lastname'] ."</option>";
}
echo'</select>';
```

If you want to get the author_id from this form, just put this value in the option's `value` attribute.

```
echo"  <option value='". $row['author_id'] ."'>" . $row['author_firstname'] . $row['author_lastname'] ."</option>";
```

Don't forget to give a `name` to your `select` tag.

Comment: Hey yes, thank you for that. I'm waiting also for the author_id to be resolved. Glad that you also answer it. Please wait for 5 minutes to be accepted it :)

Comment: What's wrong with the author_id? I suggested a solution but maybe I didn't understand what was the issue?

Comment: It's originally a `book` table, and the author is a foreign key. And sorry, for the misunderstanding. Because, you originally answer it without it.

Comment: Yes I edited my answer, I missed the 'PS' at first (my fault I should have commented to mention it). :)