# php - Adding foreign key to MySQL using <option><select>

Tags: php, mysql

This is a follow up question to my previous question in here. [PHP - Dropdown menu(select) not working properly to while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721964/php-dropdown-menuselect-not-working-properly-to-while-loop)

I follow the code given to me and I think it is working correctly. But my only concern is that, the query in my code is actually for the `shelf` table, and not for the `book` table which have the foreign key for the shelf. Here is my code for the textfield. It is in a form which have a button that redirects to check_book.php to add it

```
<div class="form-group">

      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Shelf</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
    <?php   
    $sel_admin = "select * from shelf";
    $rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
    echo '<select class="form-control">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin))
                {

                echo"<option value='" .$row['shelf_id']."'>" . $row['shelf_description'] ."</option>";
                }
                echo'</select>';
                ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It's giving me this error
 `Notice: Undefined index: shelf_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\OCatalog\admin\check_book.php on line 8`
but the other non-foreign key textfield is just fine.

And here is my check_book.php

```
$book_id = $_POST['book_id'];
    $book_title = $_POST['book_title'];
    $author_id = $_POST['author_id'];
    $book_quantity = $_POST['book_quantity'];
    $shelf_id = $_POST['shelf_id'];
```

How can I view all the `shelf` then adding it as a foreign key?

PS. The select is also in the `form` which when i click the submit button it will go to check_book.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put a name attribute in your select

```
echo '<select class="form-control" name="shelf_id">';
```

Comment: Hey yeah the error goes down to 1 error. But it says that the`book_id` is undefined variable? I check my other forms and Im pretty sure i just copy it but it can add well without declaring the `_id`

Comment: Sorry man, I forgot to mark your answer as correct. Yes, this is the method I used. my concern is just it doesn't read the `auto_increment` `book_id` to which i have already been solved by adding a hidden textfield. Kudos!